# Build a list from kotlin flow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to build an application that use kotlin flows from the data layer up to the view but struggle so much with simple problems like this one.

I'm collecting integer values from a StateFlow coming from my data layer, and would like to build a list out of it before I share it to me viewmodel and view throught another StateFlow.

Sample code:

```kotlin
class MyDataSource {
    val inputFlow: StateFlow<Int> = TODO()
}

class MyService(
    dataSource: MyDataSource
) {
    private val intList: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()

    private val _intFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<Int>>(listOf())
    val intFlow: StateFlow<List<Int>> = _intFlow

    init {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            dataSource.inputFlow.collect {
                if (!intList.contains(it))
                    intList.add(it)
                
                _intFlow.emit(ArrayList(intList))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't there a better way to do this? Like a flow operator I missed? It seems especially ugly since I need to build a new ArrayList every time because other wise even if the content of the List changed the flow won't send the new value as it is still the same List.

Comment: Hi are you following MVVM ? Your service class code isn't a viewModel, are you looking for an example ?

Comment: @ZaidZakir It could be part of a ViewModel but I chose to externalize it to another layer that I call "Services" (similar to how some apps have a "Repository" layer, but my app is more "business logic heavy" and make way less usage of external API). But I don't understand how is that relevant to my question.

Answer (score 1):

There is some cleanup you can do, but I think the arrangement of flowing an ever growing list is too specific for there to be any all-in-one solution in the core library.

1. You should [avoid using GlobalScope](https://elizarov.medium.com/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc). This service class should more properly have its own scope so you can manage lifecycle if need be.
2. Your backing list should be a set since you are in effect using it as a poor-performance set by checking if the objects are in it before adding to it.
3. It would be cleaner to use chain operators and `stateIn` rather than manipulating a MutableStateFlow and having to use a backing property.

```
class MyService(
    dataSource: MyDataSource
) {
    private val intSet = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    val intFlow = dataSource.inputFlow
        .map {
            intSet += it
            intSet.toList()
        }.stateIn(scope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, emptyList())
}
```

Edit: Here's an untested attempt at avoiding set-to-list copies and new allocations on each iteration:

```
class MyService(
    dataSource: MyDataSource
) {
    private val intSet = mutableSetOf<Int>()
    private var currentList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    private var previousList = mutableListOf<Int>()
    private var lastEmittedValue: Int? = null
    private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    val intFlow = dataSource.inputFlow
        .mapNotNull { newValue ->
            if (!intSet.add(newValue)) 
                return@mapNotNull null
            lastEmittedValue?.let {
                previousList += it
            } // both backing lists now identical
            lastEmittedValue = newValue
            previousList = currentList.also { currentList = previousList }
            // previousList is the one missing lastEmittedValue on next iteration:
            currentList += newValue
            currentList
        }.stateIn(scope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, emptyList())
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Only thing that bother me is that you still use toList() to recreate a new List every time, isn't that resource heavy in the long run? (I simplified my code a lot, in reality I manipulate a List of complex objects that I can add, remove or edit in the List).

Comment: The StateFlow class has to have a way to distinguish emitted objects. It won't emit two equivalent objects in a row, so if the two objects in a row are the same instance, it can't compare them. I suppose you could hack it by having two backing Lists and alternating between them, but that sounds fragile to me, because of how tricky it would be to keep them both correct with the backing data. You'd need another property to keep the most recent value that is only in one list and needs to be added to the other after the next value arrives.

Comment: Note that you were already copying your backing list to a new List instance on each iteration in your original code. The complexity of the underlying object is irrelevant to the performance of list copies, since the Set/List only contain references to the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Does `scan` do what you need?

From the docs:

> Folds the given flow with operation, emitting every intermediate result, including initial value. [...] For example:
>
> `flowOf(1, 2, 3).scan(emptyList<Int>()) { acc, value -> acc + value }.toList()`
> will produce `[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]`.

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/scan.html